# Need help complex correlation analysis (150 columns against 36)

Tags: r, correlation, pearson-correlation

I have to carry out a relatively complex correlation analysis, in which a total of 150 columns are to be examined of correlation against 36 other columns. I have already done this for 30 columns against the 36, which was very time-consuming, since I carried out the analysis with a separate command function for each of the 30 columns.
Here is my example dataset:

```
df <- structure(list(x1 = c(0.2569, 0.0145896, 0.0369, 0.025986,
                     0.12569, 0.3695), x2 = c(0.125, 0.04582, 0.2569, 0.256369, 0.25698, 0.1456), x3 = c(0.2584, 0.05698, 0.1258, 0.2569, 0.098563, 0.1569), 
                          y1 = c(21, 36, 25, 10, 36, 5), y2 = c(12, 25, 13, 44, 69,23)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

So my real dataset consists of x1,...,x150 and y1,...,y36. And my aim is

- to get the pearson correlation coefficients with p-values between x1-y1, x1-y2, x2-y1, x2-y2, x3-y1 and x3-y2 and so on
- the results for x1, x2 and so on should be a new data.frame in the global environment with names like x1, x2 (column name)

The only solution I have is the one from this page:
[compute correlation in R between two columns from different data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24201222/compute-correlation-in-r-between-two-columns-from-different-data-frame)
, but then I would have to run it 150 times on my data set. Is there a way to do this in a loop? How can you formulate that? The loop notation is unfortunately still quite abstract for me. It would probably be better for this to store the y-data in a separate data set?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one method for doing pairwise between `x*` and `y*` variables in the same frame:

```r
out <- outer(
  setNames(nm=grep("^x", names(df), value=TRUE)),
  setNames(nm=grep("^y", names(df), value=TRUE)),
  FUN = function(a, b) mapply(cor, df[a], df[b]))
out
#            y1         y2
# x1 -0.5226603 -0.2180721
# x2 -0.1469443  0.4764507
# x3 -0.6718297 -0.1850078
```

Explanation:

- `grep("^x", names(df), value=TRUE)` will return (in this example `c("x1","x2","x3")`, all x-leading variable names;
- `setNames(nm=..)` turns that into a named vector, `c(x1="x1",...)`, this helps by adding the row/column names to the resulting matrix;
- `outer` does a cartesian join of the values between the two vectors, and when it calls its function (`FUN=`), it calls them *all at once*. The function used here needs to be able to handle one call with `a` being really long. Obviously `cor` doesn't like that, so we use `mapply` to vectorize in a sense. For instance, if we debug that, then within the `FUN` function, we'll see

  ```r
  # debug at #1: mapply(cor, df[a], df[b])
  a
  #   x1   x2   x3   x1   x2   x3 
  # "x1" "x2" "x3" "x1" "x2" "x3" 
  b
  #   y1   y1   y1   y2   y2   y2 
  # "y1" "y1" "y1" "y2" "y2" "y2"
  ```

  We need to convert that vector into lists of data, so we use `[`. (I use `as.list` below because it normally returns a `data.frame` ... which is really just a `list` with special formatting, but I want to highlight that `mapply` just cares about getting lists of data.)

  ```r
  as.list(df[a])
  # $x1
  # [1] 0.2569000 0.0145896 0.0369000 0.0259860 0.1256900 0.3695000
  # $x2
  # [1] 0.125000 0.045820 0.256900 0.256369 0.256980 0.145600
  # $x3
  # [1] 0.258400 0.056980 0.125800 0.256900 0.098563 0.156900
  # $x1.1
  # [1] 0.2569000 0.0145896 0.0369000 0.0259860 0.1256900 0.3695000
  # $x2.1
  # [1] 0.125000 0.045820 0.256900 0.256369 0.256980 0.145600
  # $x3.1
  # [1] 0.258400 0.056980 0.125800 0.256900 0.098563 0.156900
  ```

  and similarly for `df[b]`.

  What `mapply` does is call `cor` with the first element of `df[a]` with the first element of `df[b]`, then it calls `cor` with the second element of `df[a]` with the second element of `df[b]`, etc.
- finally, `outer` formats its output as a matrix (named, since we added `setNames(nm=...)`; if you want it as a three-column frame, that's easy enough: wrap in `as.data.frame.table(...)`:

  ```r
  as.data.frame.table(out)
  #   Var1 Var2       Freq
  # 1   x1   y1 -0.5226603
  # 2   x2   y1 -0.1469443
  # 3   x3   y1 -0.6718297
  # 4   x1   y2 -0.2180721
  # 5   x2   y2  0.4764507
  # 6   x3   y2 -0.1850078
  ```

  If you don't like the name, then change it:

  ```r
  as.data.frame.table(out, responseName='correlation')
  #   Var1 Var2 correlation
  # 1   x1   y1  -0.5226603
  # 2   x2   y1  -0.1469443
  # 3   x3   y1  -0.6718297
  # 4   x1   y2  -0.2180721
  # 5   x2   y2   0.4764507
  # 6   x3   y2  -0.1850078
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your very well explanation! When I try to run "as.list(df[a])", I get an error message that df[a] is unknown. He accepted the outer command without any problems and I get the same results. Do I have to do something else after "outer" and before "as.list"? and since I also need the p-values, could I simply replace cor with cor.test?

Comment: That's within a debugging session _inside_ of the `outer` internal anonymous function. Run `outer(..., FUN = function(a, b) { browser(); ...; })` where `...` are as I have in the full code. You'll be able ot see it then.